# How to display widget in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Just following a along some examples from the library [documentation](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Alignment.html), I tried to get a widget to show, like this:

```
VBox([HBox([Button(), FloatRangeSlider(), Text(), Button()]),
      HBox([Button(), FloatText(),
            FloatProgress(value=40), Checkbox(description='Check')]),
      HBox([ToggleButton(), IntSlider(description='Foobar'),
            Dropdown(options=['foo', 'bar']), Valid()]),
     ])
```

But I get instead:

```
<function ipywidgets.widgets.widget_box.VBox>
```

Comment: Try a=VBox and then a()

Comment: that gives me an empty widget.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is pretty straight forward:

```
from IPython.display import display

a = VBox([HBox([Button(), FloatRangeSlider(), Text(), Button()]),
          HBox([Button(), FloatText(),
          FloatProgress(value=40), Checkbox(description='Check')]),
          HBox([ToggleButton(), IntSlider(description='Foobar'),
          Dropdown(options=['foo', 'bar']), Valid()]),
 ])

display(a)
```

See picture:
[image]